# How to DRY requires in a Node Express app?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a Node + Express app. In many of my files I am doing this at the top

```
const config = require('./config');
const Twit = require('twit');
const TwitConnector = new Twit(config);
```

Is there a way to DRY this, so I don't have to repeat this everywhere?

Is there a, best practice, pattern to make something like `TwitConnector` globally available so that I can use it anytime I need it?

Or maybe that's not a good idea and explicitly requiring it is the right thing to do?

Comment: Using a global is asking for trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you make twit-connector.js file and require that instead? I don't think making it global is a good idea.

**twit-connector.js**

```
const config = require('./config');
const Twit = require('twit');
const TwitConnector = new Twit(config);

module.exports = TwitConnector;
```

**somefile.js**

```
const TwitConnector = require('./twit-connector');

// do something with TwitConnector
```

Comment: Yea I thought about this, and this is a valid solution. However, I was hoping for something that would completely remove the need to `require('./twit-connector');`... But thank you.

Comment: A single require won't be that bad. It's much better than making a global.